# Verifying a JWT encrypted token with ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

After scavenging bits and pieces from the net and trying to make it work, I gave up.

So here it is:

I have an OpenID token with a signature encryption of RSA-SHA256.
I've tried the following code using JWT.net library

This is the token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ii11Zm0wSEVuMVpSbktHV2ZmQUttd0h0bEV4RSJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbG9uIiwiYXVkIjoiMTIzNDUiLCJqdGkiOiJMeVlDeGo4MzNEbHV3V2h0Q0s4OXZmIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly8xMC4xNDYuMzIuMTY0OjkwMzEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDUwMjU4NjYsImV4cCI6MTY0NTAyNjE2NiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjQ1MDI1ODY2fQ.KtS1WR3A61uSalUfrwbORx8AcYtsqudj9KlzFmf98W8PbwpSUu0axJmDYjHnH35ltYDjiZgX06RMKOSWQILt2O_4P2T1DtKUz0UOLjW04rpbz-pyOuw6sxQMHOQNUsUt_effojsBB6ISA6ejs-DKx652_M0JYMdZ_GnN2CODJdpZQIYI7xTgaOVrJjjzcxeczcMkGMTryS0qN8U4Pjy9Y4TAVTgSDw3Ca-dw-abwI4oY1aZILDEHglcCVcSMC5Vu6uO1BiLTD7Gc7wbMUi05OPxDrv4xumXVYVDpXhM4kENnoK3_gmGZMQ3SvFWAcFahwR-lyb8gisK8gZZ19PG-Iw
```

This is the latest code I've tried:

```
 string modulus = "w7Zdfmece8iaB0kiTY8pCtiBtzbptJmP28nSWwtdjRu0f2GFpajvWE4VhfJAjEsOcwYzay7XGN0b-X84BfC8hmCTOj2b2eHT7NsZegFPKRUQzJ9wW8ipn_aDJWMGDuB1XyqT1E7DYqjUCEOD1b4FLpy_xPn6oV_TYOfQ9fZdbE5HGxJUzekuGcOKqOQ8M7wfYHhHHLxGpQVgL0apWuP2gDDOdTtpuld4D2LK1MZK99s9gaSjRHE8JDb1Z4IGhEcEyzkxswVdPndUWzfvWBBWXWxtSUvQGBRkuy1BHOa4sP6FKjWEeeF7gm7UMs2Nm2QUgNZw6xvEDGaLk4KASdIxRQ";
 string exponent = "AQAB";

 try
 {
     IDictionary<string, object> claims = Decode(token, modulus, exponent);
}
catch (SignatureVerificationException ex)
{
     // signature invalid, handle it here
     return false;
}
return true;

private static IDictionary<string, object> Decode(string token, string modulus, string exponent)
{
    var urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();

    var rsaKey = RSA.Create();
    rsaKey.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters()
        {
            Modulus = urlEncoder.Decode(modulus),
            Exponent = urlEncoder.Decode(exponent)
        });

    var claims = new JwtBuilder()
            .WithAlgorithm(new RS256Algorithm(rsaKey))
            .MustVerifySignature()
            .Decode<IDictionary<string, object>>(token);

    return claims;
}
```

I get the following error:

> The signature is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Now, I don't really know what this modulus and exponent strings are. I just copied them from the example someone gave, so I don't know if it's related to my problem.

This code is also making no use of my secret key.

I did not generate the token myself. A 3rd-party authorization server is generating that.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 5
But it seems that a missing public key is my issue at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulus and exponent are parts of an RSA key, it is basically trying to recreate the RSA key from known values (whether that works like you have or not I don't know).

Anyway, you can use instead the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which is in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package. All you have to do then is pass in the relevant parameters directly (the actual RSA key) and it will validate and give you back the valid token if if it succeeds. Something like this:

```
SecurityToken validatedToken;
ClaimsPrincipal principal = validator.ValidateToken(jwtToken, GetValidationParameters(), out validatedToken);
```

where the validation parameters are like this:

```
private TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
        {
            return new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = GetRSAKey(),
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfig.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = jwtConfig.Audience,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = GetMethodToResolveExternalKey(),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };
        }
```

Note that the signing key and the signing key resolver are separate techniques. You can pass the key directly if you have it locally but if you need to look it up somewhere else (like Azure Key Vault) you can pass a method which will be called with the name of the key specified in the JWT token.

Comment: These 2 keys... where do I get them from? There are no other keys available to me in the administration console of the authorization server other than a "secret key"

Comment: Where is the key that was used to sign the original token? You need access to the public key for that otherwise you cannot verify the token. If it is hosted on an endpoint from the service that supplied the token then you will need to obtain (probably from jwks endpoint) and then convert from base64 back into key.

Comment: I'll ask them where do I get it from.

Comment: do I also need the private key in order to verify it? I don't see any usage of that in your code.

Comment: No, only the public key is used for verification.